# Spectacle in Kubuntu 20.04.2: every time I take a screenshot it opens a new instance window. Could the program reuse the same instance?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I'm using Kubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and every time I take a screenshot with Spectacle (version 19.12.3) it opens a new instance window leaving me with multiple windows after a while. Is there a way to make it reuse the same instance and avoid the extra windows? I don't remember this was the behavior before. Thank you.

Comment: I use a shortcut to trigger the window, but before it was the same.  The only thing it changed was that it's a new install and a different OS, I previously was using Linux Mint 20. This is a screenshot of my current shortcut: [link](https://i57.servimg.com/u/f57/13/44/18/95/screen25.png)

Comment: So, every time a trigger the keyboard shortcut, it spawns a new window. Please, take a look at this demonstration screenshot: [Windows](https://i57.servimg.com/u/f57/13/44/18/95/screen26.png)

Comment: Which shortcut? I am using the exact same version of Ubuntu and the exact same version of Spectacle and I can't replicate the behavior. Each successive screenshot replaces the one before it- new windows are not spawned.

Comment: The shortcut? The one in the first screenshot, the one it says "Capture Active Window", I chose for that Meta+Print. I don't know why you can't replicate it, but if you look at the second screenshot a new window spawns.  How can I stop that behavior!?

Comment: Does this behavior persist even after changing application settings? Is "*Open a new Spectacle window*" selected under "*When Spectacle is Running/ Press screenshot key to:*"

Comment: Unfortunately is not selected. The settings are set in [Take a new screenshot](https://i57.servimg.com/u/f57/13/44/18/95/screen27.png) I experimented selecting all the different options and the behavior is still the same, it opens a new window only. Could it be a permissions issue?

Comment: I just tested this using a live session of Kubuntu 20.04.2 and Spectacle 19.12.3.  The behavior is exactly the same as my installed system when taking successive screenshots from keybinds-- no new windows are spawned.  There must be something on your installed system to change this behavior. If not the settings for this particular application, possibly another setting somewhere else. This is not the default behavior of the app, although as mentioned in my previous comment, you can change application settings to achieve the behavior you are experiencing.

Comment: This is [my spectaclerc file](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TXhVBDS8XB/) located in ~/.config The permissions for that file is 755. Is there any other config file that spectacle could be reading instead of the one in .config?

Comment: I found a solution! I deleted the print command and added it again and now everything stays in a single window! Thank you for all the help! By the way, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was that I deleted the global print command and added it again, after this every snapshot stays in a single window as intended.